# Snap SVG - Can I use multiple variables initialising snap.svg to point to different svg ID's in the markup?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

Essentially I would like to build a red and a blue template in my main.js to have different colour versions of the same set of shapes (for the time being) using snap.svg.

My idea was to build one snap initialising variable "b" which points to the svg with the id of #svg-red, and then create another snap initialising variable "r" which would point to #svg-blue id. The blue and red variables would then have their own separately drawn circles and attributes.

That would've presumably allowed me to switch between templates by simply changing the id of my svg div in my markup.

This however whenever I define the Snap command into more than one variable that is used, all the shapes dissapear.

Any other simple SVG/JS/Snap ideas are welcome (I am a newbie!) :)
My main aim is to assign templates to ID's which can easily be switched in the svg tag in the markup.

```js
window.onload = function(){

//    Blue template which should point to #svg-blue
    
    var b = Snap("#svg-blue");
    
    var cir_1 = b.circle(50,50,50);
    var cir_2 = b.circle(150,150,50);
    var cir_3 = b.circle(250,50,50);

    
    
    cir_1.attr({
        fill:'lightBlue'
    });
    
    cir_2.attr({
        fill:'lightBlue',
        opacity:.7
    });
    
    cir_3.attr({
        fill:'lightBlue',
        opacity:.5
    });
    
//    Red template which should point to #svg-blue
    
    var r = Snap("#svg-red");
    
    var cir_1_red = r.circle(50,50,50);
    var cir_2_red = r.circle(150,150,50);
    var cir_3_red = r.circle(250,50,50); 

    
    cir_1_red.attr({
        fill:'red'
    });
    
    cir_2_red.attr({
        fill:'red',
        opacity:.7
    });
    
    cir_3_red.attr({
        fill:'red',
        opacity:.5
    });
    
};
```

```css
svg {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SVG Template</title>
    <script src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    
<!--SVG div where the snap main.js templates point to. svg-red can be replaced with svg-blue-->
    <svg id="svg-red"></svg>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not quite sure from the question why not just have the same single set of shapes, with a css class including a fill that you switch to change the colour.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my work around. I separated the snap svg templates into functions, and then call them up individually through the onload command on the svg tag in the markup. I then replaced the snap svg initialising variable to a generic "s" throughout the templates, and replaced the svg's id in the markup to the generic #svg. Now all i have to do is swap out the function name on the onload command to change templates.

I know I could be coding 'dryer', but when ever i don't have the variables in each separate function I get 'undefined variable'. If anyone has any better refinements, I'd be grateful!

```js
//Working method!
    
function blue(){
    
    var s = Snap("#svg");
    
    var cir_1 = s.circle(50,50,50);
    var cir_2 = s.circle(150,150,50);
    var cir_3 = s.circle(250,50,50);

//    Blue template 
    
    cir_1.attr({
        fill:'lightBlue'
    });
    
    cir_2.attr({
        fill:'lightBlue',
        opacity:.7
    });
    
    cir_3.attr({
        fill:'lightBlue',
        opacity:.5
    });
};
    

function red(){ 
    
    var s = Snap("#svg");
    
    var cir_1 = s.circle(50,50,50);
    var cir_2 = s.circle(150,150,50);
    var cir_3 = s.circle(250,50,50);
    
//    Red template 

    
    cir_1.attr({
        fill:'red'
    });
    
    cir_2.attr({
        fill:'red',
        opacity:.7
    });
    
    cir_3.attr({
        fill:'red',
        opacity:.5
    });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SVG Template</title>
    <script src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    
<!--SVG div where the snap main.js templates point to. Different functions are called up through the onload command-->
    <svg id="svg" onload="blue();"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```